# Number of possible 3x3 matrices with 0,1 entries

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a $3\times 3$ matrix whose entries can be $0$ or $1$.

How many patterns can I make with this?

I know it has something to do with the binomial coefficient, but I haven't studied it in Yeats.

Answer (score 4):

There are $9$ entries, any of which can be $0$ or $1$. That gives $2^9$ possibilities.

For imagine that you want to produce such a matrix. We will make the first row, then the second, then the third.

For the first entry we have $2$ choices. For every such choice, there are $2$ choices for the second entry. So the first two entries can be chosen in $2\times 2$ ways. For every choice of the first two entries, there are $2$ choices for the third entry, for a total of $(2\times 2)\times 2=2^3$.

Now we start on the second row. For every one of the $2^3$ ways of choosing the first row, there are $2$ choices for the first entry in the second row. So our first four entries can be chosen in $2^4$ ways. Continue.